# Raspbian network-manager-gnome

Tags: networking, gsm

Because I wanted to connect a GSM modem in Raspberry PI, I installed network-manager-gnome
Does anybody know why the following messages appears after I set-up any connection?

Connection activation failed
(32) Not authorized to control networking...

Maybe the old network manager is still in place. If this is true, how can I remove it?

(EDIT)
The answer given [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15209/using-network-manager-for-wireless-vpn-management/15255#15255) is not working for me.

Comment: it is not really a duplicate of [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/15209/23017), but you can find your answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/15255/23017).

Comment: I found that question / answer but is not working for me.